# Draggable droppable knockoutjs sortable accordion and back... (puh)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, draggable, droppable

I have a sortable jQuery accordion with a customized for each-loop data-binding.
Now I want to drop an item from my accordion and onto a "parking place".

I used the jQuery UI´s "Shopping Cart" as a starting point.

This is my code:

First the HTML accordion-loop:

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion: { },template: { name: tasktemplate', foreach: Tasks, afterAdd: function(elem){$(elem).trigger('valueChanged');} }" class="group accordion ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix" ></div>   

<!-------------------- template: begins --------------------->

<script type="text/html" task-template" >
    <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Task' + TaskId}, click: $root.SelectedTask" class="group ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" >
        <div class="accordion-header  ui-widget-header">
            <table class="myAccordionHeaderTable" >
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left-upper" ><label for="TaskSequenceNo">Seq:</label> <span data-bind="text: TaskSequenceNo"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="center" rowspan="2" >
                            <h3><input name="TaskName" data-bind="value: TaskName" /></h3>
                        </td>
                        <td class="right-upper" colspan="2">Due: <span data-bind="text: DueDate"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left-bottom">Id: <span data-bind="text: TaskId" ></span></td>
                        <td class="right-bottom" title="Number of employees attached to task">T: <span data-bind="text: TaskEmployees"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <label for="Description" >Description:</label><textarea name="Description" data-bind="value: Description" class="description"></textarea>
        </div>                      
    </div>
</script>
<!-------------------- template: ends ----------------------->
```

and the "Parking Spot":

```
<div id="parking" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
    <h2 class="ui-widget-header">Parking</h2>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <div>
            <span class="placeholder">Park tasks here</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data-binding of the accordion is like this (interesting part is the "$(element).draggable(...)" at the bottom):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        $(element).accordion(options);
        $(element).bind("valueChanged", function () {
            ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion.update(element, valueAccessor);
       });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor();

    $(element).accordion("destroy").accordion({
        header: ".accordion-header",
        collapsible: true,
        navigation: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false
    })
        .sortable({
            axis: "x, y",
            handle: ".accordion-header",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                //change bool to true
                sorting = true;

                //find what tab is open, false if none
                active = $(this).accordion("option", "active");

                //possibly change animation here (to make the animation instant if you like)
                $(element).accordion("option", "animate", {
                    easing: 'swing',
                    duration: 0
                });

                //close tab
                $(element).accordion({
                    active: false
                });
            },
            over: function (event, ui) {
                $(element).accordion({
                    active: false
                });
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //1st: Handle the visible impression during sorting...
                // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
                //possibly change animation here; { } is default value
                $(element).accordion("option", "animate", {});
                //open previously active panel - set active to 'false' to maintain closed.
                active = false;
                $(element).accordion("option", "active", active);
                //change bool to false
                sorting = false;
                //alert("element=" + element);
                //2nd: Create sequence listing of items for later saving
                var items = [];
                var itemSeqNos = [];

                ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each(function () {
                    //compare data('index') and the real index
                    if ($(this).data('index') != $(this).index()) {
                        items.push(this.id);
                        itemSeqNos.push(this.id.replace("Task", "")); // Remove prefix ("Task") to build SequenceNo-array... NB!! Could this record been built only with items involved and not whole list to reduce traffic ????
                    }
                });

                ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');

                //Collect data from the accordion to set selected and set new sequence no.
                var context = ko.contextFor(this);
                //add a child to the appropriate parent, calling a method off of the main view model (context.$root)
                context.$root.isAccordionSorted(itemSeqNos); // THIS WORKS!!!
            }
        })
        .on({
            click: function () {
                $("#debug").text("-on Click: ");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#debug").text("------");
                }, 1000);
            },
            stop: function () {
                $("#debug").text("-on Stop");
                $(this).siblings().andSelf().each(function (i) {
                    $(this).data('index', i);
                });
            }
        })
        .trigger('stop');
    $(element).draggable({
            handle: "div.accordion-header",
            axis: "x, y",
            cancel: "invalid",
            cursor: "move",
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
}
```

};

Then at last the droppable code for the "Parking Spot":

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#parking div").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverclass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function(event, ui){
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<div></div>").text( ui-draggable.text() ).appendTo(this);
        }
    }).sortable({
        items:"span:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function(){
            // gets addde unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
            // using connectWithSortable fixed this, but doesn\t allow customizee active/hoverClass options
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Basically what I want is:
   1. Being able to drag drop an item from the accordion "
   2. Drop the item onto the "Parking Spot" 
   3. Hide DueDate and TaskEmployees but the TaskName in the accordion-header.

Next step:
   4. Drag and drop the item back from the Parking.

Comment: You are getting into the realm of asking others to write code for you.  Generally it is best to try it yourself, run into problems, and ask small chunk-sized questions related to problem resolution.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Comment: That is not my intention @PWKad. I have removed my further steps to narrow this down to the problem I have been struggling with for a while, namely to get the droppable to accept my accordion-structure.

Comment: Thanks @DhanaKrishnasamy! This looks promising. :)